# Trying to think recursively about Django forms on one to many models

Tags: django, forms, recursion

I have a mental block when it comes to recursion. So, I'm not sure if I'm thinking straight or if there's a better way to do this. I have a model for visits, and a model for visitors:

```
class Inquiry (models.Model):
    arrival      = models.DateField("arrival date")
    departure    = models.DateField("departure date")
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    visitors     = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Visitor (models.Model):
    inquiry     = models.ForeignKey(Inquiry)
    surname     = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    givenname   = models.CharField("given name",max_length=80)
    middlename  = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
```

I would like for the inquiry form to ask for the number of visitors (among other things) and then subsequently generate a form for each visitor on a separate web page. In other words, for three visitors, users would need to click submit four times: once for the inquiry form, and then once each for the three visitor forms.

I'm thinking something like:

```
def inquiry(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        inquiry_form = InquiryForm(request.POST)
        if inquiry_form.is_valid():
            inquiry = inquiry_form.save()
            visitors = inquiry.visitors
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/resources/visitors/bios/%s" % (inquiry.id, visitors,)
    ...

def contact(request,inquiry, visitors):
    if visitors > 0:
        if request.method == "POST":
            visitor_form = VisitorForm(request.POST)
            if visitor_form.is_valid():
                visitor = visitor_form.save()
                visitors -= 1
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/resources/visitors/bios/%s" % (inquiry, visitors,)
    ...
    else:
        return
```

But I know I'm missing several somethings. (I looked a little at Form Wizard too, but I'm not sure if that will help me.)

Comment: Can you just use formset on the next page?

Comment: If the user specifies that they have 20 visitors, I'm trying to avoid having them scroll down 20 forms on a single page. I think I'd rather have them fill out one visitor, click submit, have the system save it, and then go on to the next form for visitor 2. Ad nauseum.